# Manage differents user types in symfony

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I build an application with different types of users (managers, users, administrators).

Each type of user can do specific things, and have specific relations with other entities. For example a Manager is linked to many Factory. But a simple User is not linked to any Factory.
So I have to manage different entities (representing different tables) for different types of users in my application.

I see that FOSUserBundle can handle only one entity for user authentication. 
So I don't know how to handle my user management.

Any idea to do this stuff?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go back to your designs a bit.  You should use user-roles to accomplish what your'e suggesting.  All your users should be of the same class type.

Your user class should have relationships setup with lets say your factory class, like this;

```
class User {

    // ....

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Factory", mappedBy="users")
     */
    private $factories;

    // .....
}
```

**and conversely** (optional: if you need to pull data in the other direction)

```
class Factory {

    // ....    

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", InversedBy="factories")
     */
    private $users;

}
```

You can then restrict/allow access either through the firewall, or directly in the controller via annotation or scripted checks.

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) for all the details that you need.

This way you can use whatever authentication that comes with FOSUserBundle.

When it comes to CRUD activities and you need formType classes.  Build a baseUser class of your own to contain all the fields that all your user types need, and extend it for each of your special cases.

Comment: ok I think I understand. But I feel like it's not beautifull that a simple user has a relation factories even if only managers can have factories. You understand?

Comment: The idea is to make extensible, easy to maintain code.  The more you complicate the structure the harder it is to use as your application gets more complex.  Its perfectly valid that an entity has an unused relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific group which contain independently her config and concept.

After you must plug those group with FOSUserBundle logic.

With the mix of 2 logical concept you can create what do you want.

Comment: the problem is if i create a Manager entity and a SimpleUser entity, FOSUserBundle will ask me the user class in the config. But I have 2 distincts user classes and I don't see how I can use FOS User stuff for 2 entities.

Comment: 2 entities is not necessary for your requirements. You can do this with just one entity user.

Comment: I think I need two. Managers are related to entities like Factory, ... and SimpleUsers are not related with these entities but with some others like Order, ... so it makes no sense to hold all these relations in one entity User.

Comment: You could take a look at Doctrine inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance.  Not sure if you could cram that into FOSUserBundle or not but it's easy enough to duplicate the misc stuff in FOSUserBundle.

Comment: I would still use a single User entity for all of these and just have roles for managers, users, and administrators.

Comment: Cerad, I think what you suggested is the good way to solve my problem. But I m not sure how I can do my own custom authentication system without using FOSUser helpers.